# What is difference between CGI and WebService?

Tags: c#, web-services, paypal, cgi

As long as I know, every web developers can get valuable services,which other developer already written, by using web services.

So I wounder why we need to use CGI services.
Because I think if web services are complete, why we need something else (like CGI).

Could any one please tell me more about how different between web service and CGI.

As long as I know , PayPal offer CGI, why PayPal don't need to offer web services?

Then, As for .net developer who trying to write e-commerce app , which one is more suitable to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, CGI came first ([See CGI](http://graphcomp.com/info/specs/cgi11.html) circ. 1995).  **IMHO**: Paypal is probably not offering a WebService because 1) [Developers don't know how  Secure their applications](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~gvj/papers/C9.pdf) and paypal cannot afford to have insecure applications interfacing with their back-end. 
2) Paypal does not want to make it easy for developers to provide middle-ware API to their system.

Okay so having said that, if you have access to a WebService version of an online service then use that, if you don't then use CGI.

Comment: thank for giving answer bank by supplying two good reference links, @ Ahmed Masud.